# Resistor with silver third band

Tags: resistors, identification, repair, colour-coding, component-values

This resistor, from the AC side of a power supply board, has a silver third ring and a white fifth ring. I've never seen such component [before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_color_code#Color_band_system) :

[image]

It reads between 8 and 12 ohms on the multimeter and is not detected by my [component tester](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/testgear/$20-lcr-esr-transistor-checker-project)

What value is it supposed to be and what does the fifth white ring means?

Thanks

Comment: Is it definitely a resistor and not an axial inductor.

Comment: White as 5th band means Mil spec solderable laeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Vishay](https://www.vishay.com/docs/49478/_dale_resistor_color_code_chart_vmn_ms0002_1612.pdf):

[image]

5th band represents Military Solderable leads.

The resistor is essentially a 4-band MIL-PRF-22684 resistor or 0.2Ω, 5%, Solderable.

From MIL-PRF-22684:

[image]

> On film resistors, this band shall be approximately 1-1/2 times the width of other bands, and indicates a solderable terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all online resistor charts, including the one you linked will tell how to decode this.

Silver as the multiplier band means multiplier of 0.01.
Gold band as the tolerance band indicates 5%.

Therefore that is a 20 x 0.01 = 0.2 ohm 5% resistor.

Comment: Do you know what the white 5th band means?

Comment: Yes, but you did not ask it. I will add it to my answer.